# How to get all identifier references using TypeScript API

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to call "getReferencedSymbolsForNode()" function using TypeScript Compiler API?

This function is defined here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/services/findAllReferences.ts

but I do not understand how to call it from TS Compiler API.

I just need to get all filenames which reference to specified ts.Node.

In other words I need to retrieve the same filenames as Atom/Visual Studio Code retunes me if I press Shift+F12 (only filenames):

[image]

Comment: Include all relevant code in question. Questions should be self contained. Once that link gets changed it renders question useless in the future and we should not have to go off site to review your problem

Comment: This is link not to my code, this is link to function I need to call.

Comment: that function is code isn't it? Now you have done another poor practice of providing image of code. Nobody can copy code from images and it is very hard to read in small devices

Comment: Man, do you even read what I write?
This is NOT a screenshot of code. This is a screenshot of Atom feature I want to implement in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the TS language service to make these kind of calls. You can create one with the TypeScript compiler API which you can learn about on the TypeScript wiki: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API

You can see a working version in the source for [typescript-vfs](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript-Website/tree/v2/packages/typescript-vfs#typescript-vfs)